# No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier is correct, everything is correct

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm having a strange issue when trying to upload my ios app, it was working perfectly fine 24 hours ago but when attempting to upload, it will not go.

I am admin on the developer and app store connect accounts. The app has existed for a few years so it's not a new app, the bundle id matches correctly and I have all proper provisioning profiles and certificates.

This issue makes zero sense since less than 24 hours ago I was able to upload the app just fine.

Any help would be great

Comment: Do cross check your app version and build number. Just in case

Comment: Already checked that, they are newer than what's there... currently 10.0.8 (4500) new build is 10.0.9 (4550)

Comment: Me too. Seems like something is messed up at Apple.

Comment: I called support. Apple is aware of issue, but may not yet have a diagnosis or fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with having two developer accounts with different permissions to the account where the app was, simply logging out of the account without access fixed the issue immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Apple had an issue today - possibly related to AppStore Connect Users and Roles changes. It looks to be resolved now - at least for me.

**Update 1**: Actually, still seeing error after uploading bits. Different error.

**Update 2**: Had to resubmit with new build number. Processing completed successfully.